# $n^{3pq} - n \equiv 0$ (mod $3pq$), where p and q are prime and $n$ is any integer Find the minimum possible value of $p+q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This problem was asked in a local Olympiad. I do not know how to proceed because I did not think Fermats little theorem is applicable to composite numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's $n$?  Or is this meant to hold for all $n$?

Comment: @lulu edited the question.